# Correct method of calling WCF service asynchronously

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await, windows-8.1

I have the WCF service which return the collection of objects.

He is working code I started with (I'm not sure it is correct):

```
List<AxaptaServiceReference.Inspection> remoteInspections = (await proxy.GetInspectionsByInspectorAsync(App._winlogin)).ToList<AxaptaServiceReference.Inspection>();
```

I need to move this call to separate class:

```
public class AxGateWay
{
    public async List<AxaptaServiceReference.Inspection> GetInspections(string _inspector) 
    {
        AxaptaServiceReference.AxaptaWebServiceClient proxy = new AxaptaServiceReference.AxaptaWebServiceClient();

        List<AxaptaServiceReference.Inspection> remoteInspections = (await task).ToList<AxaptaServiceReference.Inspection>();
        return remoteInspections;
    }
}
```

Compiler say me that async method must return Task (or Task<>).

How do I need to rewrite my method and how this method call must be if I want to be sure that my code will wait when the Web Service returns the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Compiler say me that async method must return Task (or Task<>).

Then you make your `async` method return `Task<>`:

```
public async Task<List<AxaptaServiceReference.Inspection>> GetInspectionsAsync(string _inspector) 
{
  List<AxaptaServiceReference.Inspection> remoteInspections = ...;
  return remoteInspections;
}
```

Yes, this will cause your callers to use `await`, which means they must become `async`, etc., etc. `async` will "grow" through your code base like this; this "growth" is natural and should be embraced.

Comment: What is "..." in your example?  Do I need to use await inside the method?

Comment: I just showed the relevant points. "..." is the code you already have.